Can configuration in tsconfig.json for `compilerOptions.paths` transform import paths for runtime?
I'm following the documentation for Typescript to set up path aliases. My tsconfig.json looks something like this:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "nodenext",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "paths": {
      "@helpers/*": ["./src/helpers/*"]
    }
  }
}

The structure of my code is this:
.
├── package.json
├── pnpm-lock.yaml
├── src
│   ├── cli
│   │   └── index.ts
│   └── helpers
│       ├── format
│       │   ├── index.ts
│       │   └── name.ts #  contains `getFullName` function
│       └── index.ts
└── tsconfig.json

I am trying to import src/helpers/format/name.tsinside of src/cli/index.ts file:
import { readFile } from 'fs/promises';
import { getFullName } from '@helpers/format'; //  <-- trying to use path alias instead of relative path

async function main() {
  const flags = process.argv.slice(2);
  const hasVersionFlag = flags.includes('--version');

  if (hasVersionFlag) {
    const version = JSON.parse(await readFile('./package.json', 'utf8')).version;
    console.log(`Version: ${version}`);
  }

  const hasFirstNameFlag = flags.includes('--first-name');
  const hasLastNameFlag = flags.includes('--last-name');

  if (hasFirstNameFlag && hasLastNameFlag) {
    const firstNameIndex = flags.indexOf('--first-name') + 1;
    const lastNameIndex = flags.indexOf('--last-name') + 1;

    const firstName = flags[firstNameIndex];
    const lastName = flags[lastNameIndex];

    console.log(getFullName({ firstName, lastName }));
  }
}

main();

Additionally file format/index.ts contains exported function getFullName.
When building the project with tsc -b and then running it with node like so node src/cli/index.js --version I get the following error:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078 throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '@helpers/format'
Require stack:
- /path/to/project/src/cli/index.js

I followed this answer too but it's not being clear whether Typescript somehow supports transformations of import paths. Meaning - I'd like to use simply node to execute the compiled code directly.
I was trying to achieve path aliases without using any extra tooling or bundler. Does this mean I need to use something like module-alias package if I don't want to introduce bundler to my setup?
The documentation is not clear on whether paths configuration is to be consumed by additional tooling or not (quotes and links are welcome).
 Thank you
